# How to configure JWT in .NET 5 Web API

Tags: authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I have a confusion in while doing development. I am working on .NET 5 Web API in which I have implemented JWT authentication. Then I got to know that, client application(it entire different project owned by other team in my same organization) is configured using Windows AD or SSO, not fully sure though. But still client application won't be sending userid and password in a post request which I have in my AuthController. In this case, how my APIs requests will be authenticated to check if the client has access to it or not.

Any guidance on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if they are not sending id password but they must be sending jwt token already created by SSO application that you need to again validate with same SSO server. you don't need to generate token from your API.

Comment: @CodingMytra Thanks for reply.  But I don't have access to that system. How can I validate token created by other system into my code. Thanks

Comment: as per my understanding identity servers which provides SSO are public and there are standard way of doing validation.